# blazor-net8.0-editform model not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I'm kinda stuck and out of ideas, but I have got a simple editform with 1 textbox and 1 button, that needs to bind to a model, however it doesn't seem to bind to my property somehow.
I have tried with model and editcontext but both seem to fail to bind.
Any idea what am I doing wrong, and someone can explain why it doesn't bind in the current scenario?

```
<div class="row">
    <EditForm Model="newModel" FormName="SubmitModel" OnSubmit="SubmitModel">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label for="modelName">ModelName: </label>
                <InputText id="modelName" @bind-Value="@newModel.ModelName"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>

</div>


CamModel newModel = new CamModel();

protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    context = new EditContext(newModel);
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}


private async Task SubmitModel()
{
    newModel.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    camModels.Add(newModel);
    //await modelGrid.RefreshDataAsync();        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.
I had to use @rendermode on component or route leve to make actions work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples of binding to a model and context that you can use as a reference:

When I bind to context:

```
<EditForm EditContext="@editContext" OnSubmit="@Submit1" FormName="Holodeck1">
    <InputText @bind-Value="Model1!.Id" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private EditContext? editContext;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public Holodeck? Model1 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Model1 ??= new() { Id = "3" };
        editContext = new(Model1);
    }
    private void Submit1()
    {
        var inputValue = Model1?.Id;

    }
     public class Holodeck
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

When I bind to model:

```
<EditForm Model="@Model1" OnSubmit="@Submit1" FormName="Holodeck1">
    <InputText @bind-Value="Model1!.Id" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "Holodeck1")]
    public Holodeck? Model1 { get; set; }


    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //set initial data
        Model1 ??= new() { Id="5" };
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();

    }
    private void Submit1()
    {
        var inputValue = Model1?.Id;
     
    }

    public class Holodeck
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]